# Waiting for the fetch to complete and then execute the next instruction

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is it possible to wait until the `fetch` instruction has completed before executing the next code / instruction (just like how AJAX waiting works)?

These functions are actually used to request the “privacy value” of a post from the Facebook Graph API. How can I keep an alert box from running until *everything* is over (i.e. the chained fetching in `FirstRequestToGraph` and `RequestNextPage`)?

```js
function RequestNextPage(NextPage) {
  fetch(NextPage, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      if (json.data.length == 0) {
        console.log("ended liao lur");
      }
      else {
        RequestNextPage(json.paging.next);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    });
}

function FirstRequestToGraph(AccessToken) {
  fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=posts.limit(275){privacy}%2Cname&access_token=' + AccessToken, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      NextPage = json.posts.paging.next;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    });
}

FirstRequestToGraph(AccessToken)
  .then(function() {
    RequestNextPage(NextPage); // Recursively until there's no more next page.
  })
  .then(function() {
    alert("everything has ended nicely"); // Still pop up before `RequestNextPage` completed.
  });
```

Comment: yes and no ... in `FetchRequest` you need to `return fetch ...` - and in `RunFetchRequest` you need to `FetchRquest().then(function(result) { ... this code runs after fetch finishes });`

Comment: `just like how AJAX waiting works` - you must be doing AJAX wrong ... the first A in AJAX means `asynchronous` ... which is what you're having issues with in the code above, the asynchronous nature of fetch and AJAX in general

Comment: hello, sorry to interrupt, i have tried using .then to waits for the current fetch request to complete and then execute the next, however, i don't think it works in my case as i'm not really sure 'the way i chained' the fetch request is correct or not. (i have edited the codes on my question)

Comment: doing something like this doesn't help me to solve any problem at all :(
  FirstRequestToGraph(AccessToken).then(function(){
          console.log('haha');
    });

Comment: as I said in the first comment ... you need to `return fetch ...` in `FirstRequestToGraph` - then you can use `FirstRequestToGraph().then(...)`

Comment: sorry :( 
i don't really understand what do i return in FirstRequestToGraph <"return fetch ... ">

Comment: put the word return before the word fetch ... that way you return the promise chain

Comment: thank you, i finally understand what you meant by completing the promise chain (return fetch), but however, my codes still aren't working as expected, alert(testing1234) still unable to be prompt

Comment: no no no, oh dear god no, see the `fetch(` at the TOP of the function ... put a `return` before the word `fetch`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FirstRequestToGraph(AccessToken).then(function() {
    alert('testing1234');
});

function RequestNextPage(NextPage) {
    return fetch(NextPage, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
        RequestNextPage(json.paging.next);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    });
}

function FirstRequestToGraph(AccessToken) {
    return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=posts.limit(275){privacy}%2Cname&access_token=' + AccessToken, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
        if(json.data.length !== 0 ){
           return RequestNextPage(json.paging.next);
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    });
}
```

Comment: hello again, thank you very very very much for helping :)) 
i am not sure what causes my codes not to works, the alert prompt box still pop up before the previous function ended (.then works perfectly already)

Comment: Sorry, I missed another return ... `return RequestNextPage(NextPage);` ... I've now changed the answer to be similar the code you edited after I posted the answer :p

Comment: thank you very very much!!!! appreciate it a lot! *sudden realization, and understand all the return stuff.... <3

Answer (score 36):

If you have an asynchronous function in your component, like this...

```
async getJSON() {
    return fetch('/website/MyJsonFile.json')
        .then((response)=>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{return responseJson});
}
```

Then you can call it, and wait for it download, with the *await* command, using something like this...

```
async caller() {
    const json = await this.getJSON();  // command waits until completion
    console.log(json.hello);            // hello is now available
}
```

You'll also want to update getJSON(), `return fetch()` to `return await fetch()`.

`async` is wonderful.  So is `await`.

Check it out: [Mozilla Developer Network: Async Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: can you explain the "this" keyword inside the async function? why not just "getJSON()"?

Comment: @Fusscreme `this` means the current object. (Notice how the functions are defined, sans `function` or `=>{}`.)